# When spark dataset use 'groupby' and 'pivot' function, executors are not working(add comment)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I execute groupby and pivot function by Spark(Dataset), no executors are working.

When I execute spark-submit, there's no error. But speed is slow.
The executors that were working properly when doing other work except the groupby and pivot functions
(Judging SparkUI as monitoring). If I monitor the cpu and memory using top in the master, the cpu 100% and memory values do not deviate greatly from the constant value. This state is maintained until the pivot is over, and executors work again when the save method is executed.

```
val inputPath="hdfs://master:9000/...csv"
val outputPath="hdfs://master:9000/....csv"
val df=spark.read.option("header","true").csv(inputPath)

val text = df.select(df("text"))
val date = df.select(df("date"))

val text_rdd = text.as(Encoders.STRING).rdd  
val date_rdd = date.as(Encoders.STRING).rdd

val date_text= date_rdd.zip(text_rdd) 

val split_rdd = date_text.flatMapValues(_.split(" ")) 

val date_text_DS=split_rdd.toDS()

val date_text_DS_cols=date_text_DS.withColumnRenamed("_1", "date").withColumnRenamed("_2", "text")   


 date_text_DS_cols.groupBy("date").pivot("text").agg(count("date")).na.fill(0).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header",true).save(outputPath)
```

How do I get all the executors to work when I execute a pivot function?

add comments:
[image]

I guess that the pivot job is completed when I see this picture. But master is still working. Perhaps I check if master driver program is running, but it's not. The 'pivot' is completed but master is running. I think it is contradictory.
I wonder if the 'write' code is involved. So, I delete codes after 'write'. But it reuslts same.

Comment: I'm guessing that the data has to be collected for the pivot to work. Check the source code for pivot. Some DS functions invlve a collect under the hood